# SASS - Default values for variable arguments

Tags: sass

Variable arguments was added in Sass 3.2.

```
@mixin hello($arguments...) {
    property: $arguments;
}

//Usage:
@include hello(1);
@include hello(1, 2, 3);
@include hello(1, 2);
```

However, this argument doesn't accept a default value, like so `($args...: default-value)`

Right now, I'm using this code, but is there a better way?

```
@mixin transition($values...) {
    $values: null !default;

    @if $values == null {
        $values: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    -webkit-transition: $values;
    -moz-transition: $values;
    -ms-transition: $values;
    -o-transition: $values;
    transition: $values;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any other solution than your's unfortunately.

Comment: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/810

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution does not work. When used with no arguments, e. g.

```
.foo { @include transition; }
```

the `transition` mixin returns an error:

```
() isn't a valid CSS value.
```

A variable argument can be treated as a list using the `length()` function. I suggest this solution:

```
@mixin transition($values...) {

  // Setting the default value
  @if length($values) == 0 {
    $values: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  -webkit-transition: $values;
  -moz-transition: $values;
  -ms-transition: $values;
  -o-transition: $values;
  transition: $values;
}
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5867258/

PS `all` and `ease` are [defaults](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp), so the default value can be simplified to `$values: 0.3s`.